# JQuery set dropdown values on button click

Tags: asp.net, jquery, html

I have a dropdown list and a button. When you click the button it will set all the dropdowns to a value using JQuery. The drop down is inside a div with a unique id. Is there any way I can get JQuery to set a drop down list value that is in a div without giving it a div class or id?

I've attached the html, its just three drop downs each one inside a div class.

http://pastebin.com/ne6x43QC

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input:submit').click(function(){
    $('div > select').val(1);
})
```

[See fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/PCheV/)